# Is this "copper" a verb or a noun? -- "[The ideal choice] would seem to be copper itself."

Tags: parsing

what is the place of this word "copper" in the following sentence?

> The ideal choice, when isotopic composition is used to investigate the source of copper ore, would seem to be **copper** itself.

verb or noun? *Copper* word in the [Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/copper) is a verb and noun.

[**text source**](http://gre.kaomanfen.com/learn/practise/u139485781872)

Comment: Do you think it's a verb? Why?  Do you think it's a noun? Why? Show some research and/or reasoning, please.

Comment: Copper word in the Oxford Dictionary the verb and noun.

Comment: @perspolis - Details like that are very important to include in the question. Without knowing _why_ you are confused, it's hard for the community to help clear up that confusion. And it's always good to let everyone know you're doing some research on your own (notice how, if you hover over the downvote button, it says: _This question does not show any research effort_). Finally – this is not a criticism, just something that might help you out in the future – instead of "place of this word," I think you might want to say ["part of speech"](http://partofspeech.org/). Welcome aboard.

Comment: So, what is confusing to you about those definitions? Does neither of them seem to fit? (by the way, edit your question to include the relevant definitions, as well as a link to Oxford dictionary).

Comment: @J.R. I think it is noun. However, I don't know why "would" has been used ? "The Ideal choice seems to be copper itself ".

Answer (score 2):

"would seem to be" functions like "is".

So the sentence boils down to

- ...choice. . . is copper.

(note that it does not say "to copper", nor "coppered", nor "coppering")
So if it's a verb, it is neither an infinitive, nor a participle, nor a gerund.

And in the (skeletal) structure above, "copper" can only be a *predicate nominative* or a *predicate adjective*.